# Finds the most frequent char in a string with python

Tags: python, string

I have written the bellow function to find the most frequent occurrences of a char in a string, it works well with :

1. "Hello World!"
2. "How do you do?"
3. "One" ( returns the first alphabetic char if the string has unique letters only )

It fails on the following string "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet". The most frequent letters are all with 3 occurrences and it results in a blank string instead of giving me one of them ( it should give the first one in alphabetical order )

```
def frequent_char(text):

    charset = ''.join(sorted(text))

    maxcount = 0
    maxchar = None

    for item in charset.lower():
        charcount = text.count(item)

        if charcount > maxcount :
            maxcount = charcount
            maxchar = item

    return maxchar
```

I don't what mistake I am making within the code. Can anyone help?

Comment: It doesn't actually "fail", a space is the most frequent character in that string. Just skip all whitespace, aka everythign in `string.whitespace`.

Answer (score 5):

The space  has *four* occurences in `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`.

So if your problem is

> to find the most frequent occurrences of a char in a string

your function works like a charm.

**Edit:**

Since you use both 'char' and 'letter' in your question it is not completely clear what you are asking. Since a 'char' is a much easier notion than a 'letter' in Python, I decided to interpret your question as a question about chars.

Comment: How is it unhelpful?  " " is a character and is being returned?  The program is executing as it should.

Comment: As OP isn't happy with the space he probably wants to skip all whitespace... as indicated by "the first one _in alphabetical order_" - no space in the alphabet.

Comment: Let the OP decide what he is happy or unhappy with. I will not guess the hidden meaning of a badly worded question.

Comment: Agreed.  But it isn't completely unhelpful, it does provide OP with knowledge of what is 'wrong' and how to go about improving it.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: @RMcG What do you mean by `this`?

Comment: @Lutz Horn The general answer

Comment: Again, "it should give the first one in alphabetical order" - There is no space in the alphabet.

Comment: A comment is to 'ask for more information or to suggest improvements'. That's not what I do. I answer by telling the OP that his problem is no problem.

Comment: No, you just make an assumption about his problem that is likely to be wrong (as indicated by my previous comments, I don't want to paste the same thing a third time though).

Answer (score 2):

An elegant solution is to use `collections.Counter`, see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects

```
>>> counter = Counter('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet')
```

The most frequent occurrences of a char is:

```
>>> counter.most_common(1)
[(' ', 4)]
```

If you don't care about space:

```
>>> counter.most_common(2)[1]
('m', 3)
```

Simple!

Answer (score 0):

Remove all white spaces from string for it to work.

```
def frequent_char(text):

    charset = ''.join(sorted(text))
    textTmp = text.replace(" ", "")  # add this to remove spaces
    maxcount = 0
    maxchar = None
    for item in charset.lower():
        charcount = textTmp.count(item)

        if charcount > maxcount:
            maxcount = charcount
            maxchar = item

return maxchar
```